# Jquery post not working , send multiple selected checkbox through jquery to php script

Tags: php, jquery, arrays, post, checkbox

In the php script when I echo the $_POST['AllItems '] then it shows only the last selected value 
instead of a whole string of values or array.

Below is the javascript am using :

```
$(function () {
    $('#senditems').click(function () {
        var items = $('input[name^="item"]:checked').map(function () {
            return this.value;
        }).get();

*****************************
  //here when i do alert(items); ,
 then it shows comma separated values - 1,22,321
****************************


        $.post("saveitems.php", {
            AllItems: items
        });
    });
});
```

Form is :

```
    <form>

    <input type="checkbox" name="items[1]" value="1" />
<input type="checkbox" name="items[22]" value="22" />
<input type="checkbox" name="items[321]"  value="321" />

    </form>
```

Comment: is AllItems an array of checkboxes ? can you post the code for your form too?

Comment: @Maximus2012 : dear sir, items is the collection of selected checkboxes , i have added the form code also.

Comment: @palaѕн : sir , was updating it , done now.

Comment: Your first part of js code seems to be correct as in this [**fiddle**](http://jsfiddle.net/KFYeh/). Are you getting any error in the console? Try using the `.done(function() {...}` and `.fail(function() {...}` to see if there's any error or ajax call succeeded!

Comment: @billyonecan : no sir , am not , but directly posting it , can you please give it a try in your browser. also i think there could be a problem in comstructing 'items' ? i mean do i have to do this :' var items +='  instead of ' var items = '

Comment: just one line :      var_dump($_POST['AllItems']); exit;

Comment: @billyonecan : sir did u get the whole array in the $_POST['AllItems'] or a whole string with all values?

Comment: @billyonecan : sir , can you please post your code along with the processor file. would be of great help.

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/34848/discussion-between-sqlchild-and-billyonecan)

Answer (score 2):

This is how your form should look.

```
<form id="my_form">

  <input type="checkbox" name="items[]" value="1" />
  <input type="checkbox" name="items[]" value="22" />
  <input type="checkbox" name="items[]"  value="321" />

</form>
```

Then in your php, you can iterate through all the $_POST['items']

If you want to use jQuery to post, you can use this, but is not necessary as you can add a method and action to the html in your form:

```
$('#senditems').on('click', function(){
    var form_data = $('#my_form').serialize();

    $.post({
        url: "your_php.php",
        data: form_data
    }); 
});
```

Comment: It will be easier to iterate the way I posted it.  Otherwise you have to manually check each, if it even works.  I've never done it the way you did.

Comment: Removing the index will make no difference whatsoever

Comment: @billyonecan : am posting the items values through jquery , then in the php script am  echoing the values but it shows only one value